# Exchange Boundaries and Wire Centers in France and Germany

Tags: data, telecom, europe

I am attempting to find a shapefile of wire center service areas / telephone exchanges in France and Germany.  Ideally, a point file showing the location of the actual equipment, coupled with a polygon that shows each center's service area.

To see an example of the what I'm talking about, this is the U.S. equivalent:
http://www.navmart.com/wire_center_boundaries.php

Obviously, free is best, but I open to sources who might have this available for purchase.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: you need to contact individual companies as most are privatised http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_telephone_operating_companies#France
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_telephone_operating_companies#Germany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking for Germany, I suppose you are looking for locations of ["Hauptverteiler (HVT)"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptverteiler), Englisch ["Main Distribution Frame (MDF)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_distribution_frame). Finding these locations and even more their area of distribution is non-trivial.

There was a list on the "Zukunft Breitband" initiative. Most information and a download link can be found on [this OpenStreetMap page (German)](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE%3aDSL-Hauptverteiler).

It also seams that Olaf Selke has a [KML file](http://selke.de/privater/hvt-standorte/) of this list.

For France I have no Information, start with the [Wikipedia page](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9partiteur_t%C3%A9l%C3%A9phonique).

Comment: I would also like to find this same wirecenter data for Spain, if it is available.  Free is best, but I am open to paying for the data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the boundaries (which are nowadays of a more theoretical nature), there is a list on the website of the [BNetzA](http://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/DE/Sachgebiete/Telekommunikation/Unternehmen_Institutionen/Nummerierung/Rufnummern/ONVerzeichnisse/GISDaten_ONBGrenzen/ONBGrenzen_node.html).

These denote the boundaries between areas of an equal prefix. Inside these areas, you can do calls without the prefix, when crossing the borders, people have a different prefix which you must add.